# Не работает log in во второй и следующие разы

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Привет.

Регистрация нового пользователя (ок) -> авторизация (ок) -> действия требующие присутствия текущего пользователя (ок) -> logout/ребилд проекта -> авторизация (не ок, срабатывает param.error)
В базе пользователи сохраняются, сразу после этого можно залогиниться (логин не автоматический), но на второй раз (после логаута или перезапуска проекта) уже нельзя.

Я первый раз делаю проект на спринге и использую security, поэтому процесс авторизации и регистрации копировал с [гайда](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d). Возможно в [конфигурации](https://github.com/DarthNyan/diplom/blob/master/src/main/java/github/darthnyan/configuration/SecurityConfiguration.java) ошибка.
Так же [login](https://github.com/DarthNyan/diplom/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/login.html), [регистрация](https://github.com/DarthNyan/diplom/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/registration.html), [сервис](https://github.com/DarthNyan/diplom/blob/master/src/main/java/github/darthnyan/services/UserService.java) и [контроллер](https://github.com/DarthNyan/diplom/blob/master/src/main/java/github/darthnyan/controllers/UserController.java).

Надеюсь кто-то найдет в себе силы помочь. :)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл проблему. 
Простите, что потратил ваше время.

```
@PostMapping("/posts")
public String createPost(@Valid @RequestParam String body) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = authentication.getName();
    Post post = new Post();
    User currentUser = userService.findUserByEmail(name);
    post.setBody(body);
    post.setAuthor(currentUser);
    currentUser.getPosts().add(post);
    postService.save(post);
    userService.saveUser(currentUser); // шифрование зашифрованного пароля
    return "redirect:/posts/";
}
```